# Serve error with ionic conference app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Trying to get ionic conference app (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app) working.
ionic 2.1.13
npm version: 3.10.8
node version: 6.9.1
cordova version: 6.4.0

**ionic serve -l** results in the following output:

> ionic-conference-app@ ionic:serve C:\data\app\mkb
>
> ionic-app-scripts serve "-l"
>
> [13:21:16]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.44
>
> [13:21:16]  watch started ...
>
> [13:21:16]  build dev started ...
>
> [13:21:16]  clean started ...
>
> [13:21:16]  clean finished in less than 1 ms
>
> [13:21:16]  copy started ...
>
> [13:21:16]  transpile started ...
>
> events.js:160
>
> ```
>  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>   ^
> ```
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8100
>
> at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
>
> at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
>
> at Server._listen2 (net.js:1257:14)
>
> at listen (net.js:1293:10)
>
> at net.js:1403:9
>
> at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>
> at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
>
> at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>
> at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program > 
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "r
>   " "ionic:serve" "--" "-l"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.9.1
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! ionic-conference-app@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "-l"`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-conference-app@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-
>
> scripts serve "-l"'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-conference-app package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "-l"
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> ...
>
> There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve

Any ideas as to what has gone wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried it and it was working for me. On the package.json, it's showing that it's using the latest rc3 `("ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3-201611211919")` so try to do the following:

1. Update your ionic CLI: `npm install -g ionic`
2. Delete your node folder and do again `npm install`
3. Now, what do you get with `ionic serve` ?

Answer (score 1):

the error you get is

> listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8100

looks like the port 8100 is in use. 
try running on a different port using

> --port=8101

also you can change this value in the run.js file

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests to me that the port is in use already.

In my case I closed my browser instances connected to my Ionic app and also closed down my other VS Code Ionic projects and tried running the ionic serve command again and this appeared to resolve the problem.